# Why do I write my .h file in the makefile if I never use it with g++?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, header

```
# I understand this, it runs last as Term.o and main.o have to be created
main: Term.o main.o
    g++ Term.o main.o -o run

# Why use Term.h here?
Term.o: Term.cpp Term.h
        g++ -c Term.cpp

# and here?
main.o: main.cpp Term.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I am not using Term.h when I run g++ anyway, so is there really a purpose for having them there? Though it is needed as main.cpp includes Term.h

Comment: `Term.h` tells the compiler that `Term.o` is *dependent* on `Term.h`, and if `Term.h` changes then `Term.o` needs to be rebuilt.  Likewise with `main.o` and `Term.h`.

Comment: You are using it!  When you call `g++ -c main.cpp`, one portion of that step is the inclusion of `Term.h` into the source.  It is incorrect to say the file is unused.

Comment: It's a matter of concepts and dependencies.  The line should include all dependencies.  If a header file is not use, why create it?  why list it?

Comment: You want the build system to know that stuff needs to be recompiled if the file is changed.

Comment: Do you include `Term.h` in `main.cpp` and `Term.cpp`? If not why do you have this `Term.h` header file? Else, do you understand what the `include` directive does?